# How to hide an anchor tag by href #id using css

Tags: html, css, hide, anchor, href

I have different anchor tags with href=#ids and I need to hide them using a general css rule for all of them,

```
Content xxxxxxxxx <a href="#tab1">Table 1</a>.Content xxxxxxxxxxxx <a href="#tab2">Table 2</a>
```

I was trying to use  something like this:

```
#wrap a='#tab1'{
display:none;
}
```

Any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 17):

Try using attribute selectors:

```
a[href='#tab1']{ display: none }
```

Or even simply

```
[href='#tab1']{ display: none }
```

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html

Comment: But if the anchor has `display: none` it is no longer active (meaning, clicking on a link to this anchor won't e.g. scroll down). And with `visibility: hidden` the anchor still uses the same space. Any solution to this?

Comment: I don't understand the comment: why you want a user to be able to click on a link that is hidden?

Comment: The link itself is not hidden, only the anchor that it refers to. The problem was that (in the system generating the HTML) I had no access to the original text that I wanted to scroll to and I didn't want to add some additional text just to be able to place an anchor.

Comment: Ah.  I see.  You could try: `position:absolute; visibility: hidden`

Answer (score 14):

Why not just create a CSS class for your anchors and hide them using that class?

```
<a href="#tab1" class="hiddenTab">foo</a>
```

And in your CSS:

```
a.hiddenTab {visibility:hidden; display:none;}
```

All the anchors you'd want to hide would just use "class='hiddenTab'"

Answer (score 4):

```
#wrap a[href="#tab1"]{
display:none;
}
```

Comment: Thank you @frazras you save my life

Answer (score 2):

If you want to hide all a tags which have href set, you can do this:

```
a[href] { display: none; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using `a[href*="#"] {display: none;}`
This selectors identifies a # in the `href` attribute of an anchor and if found it applies the style

You can use it in another way such as 
`header a[href*="#"] {display: none;}` So you don't mess all the anchors on the site!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `#wrap` is an id of a parent, you can use:

```
/* Hide all anchor tags which are children of #wrap */
#wrap a{ display:none; }

/* Hide all anchor tags which are direct children of #wrap */
#wrap > a{ display:none; }

/* Hide a specific anchor tag (Probably won't work in IE6 though) */
a[href="#tab1"]{ display:none; }
```