# Linking multiple parts of web page using div tag

Tags: html

I've divided web page in 2 sections vertically using div tag.

What I want is anchor tags of left div should display contents when clicked on link, in right div. How can I do dis with or without javascript?

Comment: It's good to show that you've made a little effort when you ask a question

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this:

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_iframe.asp

and

http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_iframe_target

it's pretty simple to follow I think...

Here's an example for good measure anyway:

in the div you want to populate put an iframe as follows:

```
<iframe 
      src="url_of_whatever_stuff_you_want_to_populate_it_with_initially" 
      name="my_iframe>
</iframe>
```

Then for each anchor add the target attribute:

```
<a target = "my_iframe" etc etc...
```

Comment: Thanx a lot Sheena....and yes from next time i'll take care from next time and u hav no idea hw much it helped....Thanx

Comment: @user1782992: You are welcome.  If this was the correct answer can you please accept it in the official way? There is a tick mark by the rating of each answer, if you click on it it gets coloured in

Answer (score -1):

Not possible without Javascript unless you want to resort to wonky, unintuitive CSS styles.

See here: [How to hide an anchor tag by href #id using css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9165479/how-to-hide-an-anchor-tag-by-href-id-using-css)

You're better off using a simple onClick event to show and hide those divs.